# Need help with configuration of codeblocks for Qt !

Tags: c++, codeblocks, qt4.6

codeblocks 8.02. , win xp SP2 , Qt 4.6

After installing Qt SDK, I installed QtWorkbench (codeblocks plugin that allows you to create Qt applications.) http://code.google.com/p/qtworkbench/.

I worked under instructions from that page. I opened the folder "dialogs" and in it I opened a new empty codeblocks project. Also in this folder "dialogs" I opened a new directory "complexwizard". In complexwizard is simple main.cpp :

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDesktopWidget>


class Communicate : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    Communicate(QWidget *parent = 0);

  private slots:
    void OnPlus();
    void OnMinus();

  private:
    QLabel *label;

};


void center(QWidget *widget, int w, int h)
{
  int x, y;
  int screenWidth;
  int screenHeight;

  QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();

  screenWidth = desktop->width();
  screenHeight = desktop->height();

  x = (screenWidth - w) / 2;
  y = (screenHeight - h) / 2;

  widget->move( x, y );
}


Communicate::Communicate(QWidget *parent)
 : QWidget(parent)
{
  int WIDTH = 350;
  int HEIGHT = 190;

  resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  QPushButton *plus = new QPushButton("+", this);
  plus->setGeometry(50, 40, 75, 30);

  QPushButton *minus = new QPushButton("-", this);
  minus->setGeometry(50, 100, 75, 30);

  label = new QLabel("0", this);
  label->setGeometry(190, 80, 20, 30);

  connect(plus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnPlus()));
  connect(minus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnMinus()));


  center(this, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

}

void Communicate::OnPlus()
{
  int val = label->text().toInt();
  val++;
  label->setText(QString::number(val));
}

void Communicate::OnMinus()
{
  int val = label->text().toInt();
  val--;
  label->setText(QString::number(val));
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Communicate window;

  window.setWindowTitle("Communicate");
  window.show();



  return app.exec();
}
```

Then I added, "main.cpp" in a blank project and all configured according to the instructions from that page.

When I started to compile the program, compiler always says:

*** It seems that this project has not been  built yet. Do you want to buid it now? ***

I press yes an got this message :

Process terminated with status 2 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings

In the folder "dialogs" where is a project, new files are created:

complexwizard.pro

Makefile.complexwizard

Makefile.complexwizard.Debug

Makefile.complexwizard.Release

Since I am relatively new to the world of programming, compiler and other things, this does not tell me much.

Therefore, I ask someone who has some suggestion on the basis of these symptoms to help me remove it from standstill.
If you're interested, I'll add more data that will need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'm the author of QtWorkbench and I have stopped supporting it some  time ago. I 'm pretty sure it's outdated by now. I really think that new Qt users should go with QtCreator the "official" Qt IDE to get the best support out of the box. QtWorkbench is still in Google Code in case any one wants to pick up developing it.

Comment: Full ACK on that. Use QtCreator as this is the "official" way to write applications using Qt. Also the integration with the documentation is really good. Is there a specific reason, nik_02, why you'd not use Qt Creator?